# Any ramifications with calling DseCluster.init()/close() every minute?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a 2-node DC and I’m trying to use the `DseCluster` object for health checking each node by calling `DseCluster.init()` and `close()` after. If `init()` fails, then I know that node is down. The methods are called about every minute.

Would this cause any bad side effects? (e.g. accidentally leaving too many open connections)

Answer (score 1):

That's bad practice - initialization of the `DseCluster` is quite heavyweight operation, and cluster instances should be re-used.  I would instead register [Host.StateListener](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.5/com/datastax/driver/core/Host.StateListener.html), and tracked when hosts are added, or removed from cluster, or changes their state to up, or down.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, could you elaborate on what negative effects those heavyweight operations would cause? Would it cause negative effects on the client, cluster, or
 both?